# How to draw in the complex plane iz, z $\epsilon \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I trying to do it proving number by number but I don't know how to start.

Comment: Did you know that multiplication by a complex number induces a rotation of the complex plane? This is typically shown using the polar form $e^{i\theta}$ of the complex number. Now $i=e^{i\pi/2}$, so the rotation is through the angle $\pi/2$. You can see also see this by multiplying $i$ by several really simple numbers to show for example, $1\to i\to -1\to -i\to 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z=re^{i\theta}$ (where $r=|z|$ and $\theta$ is the argument of $z$) then $$iz=e^{i\frac12\pi}re^{i\theta}=re^{i(\theta+\frac12\pi)}$$

So the absolute value of $iz$ (i.e. its distance from the origin) is the same as the absolute value of $z$ and its argument has increased with $\frac12\pi$. An angle of $90$ degrees counterclockwise.

I am too lazy to make a picture. Maybe someone else will do that for you.

Comment: But how do you rotate all numbers in $C$? there would be no difference with the original complex plane right?

Comment: The map $z\mapsto iz$ is indeed a bijection, if that's what you mean. The map $z\mapsto -iz$ is its inverse.

Comment: I mean if the picture of $zi$ is the same as the complex plane. I'm suposse to rotate all numbers and draw the result, but if I rotate all numbers then the plane is the same right?

Comment: Strange that you are asked to do that. It's like rotating a disk and draw the result. The result has the same look as the original but still "something happened". Drawing just a picture is not efficient in making clear what exactly happened.

Comment: I will put an explanation. Thanks for the explanation :) For casuality do you know a good book about complex numbers for beginners? In my analysis book the chapter of the complex numbers has only 10 pages :(

Comment: I would recommend Schaum's outline series Complex Variables (that's my main source). You might find it on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation $T(z)=iz$ acts as:
$$T(z)=T(x+iy)=i(x+iy)=-y+ix$$

using the canonical isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ this is equivalent to:
$$
T (x,y)^T=(-y,x)^T$$

so $T$ is represented by the matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that is a rotation of $\pi/2$ counterclockwise around the origin.